# Pandas - groupby result as table

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, plotly

I'm new to pandas and plotly and am currently working on a small analysis project looking at my Netflix data.

I'm trying to display a table of my top 10 films (by max. duration watched). I have:

`top10 = df.groupby(['Film Title'])['Duration'].sum().nlargest(10)`

and

```
table = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
    header=dict(values=('Title', 'Total Time Watched'),
                fill_color='#66c5cc',
                align='left'),
    cells=dict(values=['', top10],
               align='left'),
)])
table.update_layout(title_text="Top 10 Series through the Years", title_x=0.5)
```

This results in a table that looks like this:

[result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYvJm.png)

I can't find a way to also get the titles of the films connected to the "top 10" list to be able to insert that into the "values" in "cells". The "top 10" list only displays the duration. I tried changing the index of "top10", and to create a list, but I can't find an answer. It's probably something very simple, but I'm new to programming, so, no idea where the error is :/

Appreciate your help! Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're putting blank values `''` in your cell values, you need to fill it with the values you want, in this case it's your groupby index: `top10.index`

```
table = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
    header=dict(values=('Title', 'Total Time Watched'),
                fill_color='#66c5cc',
                align='left'),
    cells=dict(values=[top10.index, top10],
               align='left'),
)])
table.update_layout(title_text="Top 10 Series through the Years", title_x=0.5)
```

Comment: yes, I was aware of the blank values, just didn't know what to put in there. top10.index worked! thank you :)